# Registry tab does not work

Tags: gitlab

I have installed gitlab on AWS server and it is working as expected.

http://ec2-54-167-34-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

But when I click on "Registry" tab, I am shown page not found error (500)

---

The relevant part from /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_projects_features_container_registry'] = true

# registry_external_url 'https://registry.gitlab.example.com'
registry_external_url 'http://ec2-54-167-34-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com:4567'

# Settings used by GitLab application
gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['registry_host'] = "http://ec2-54-167-34-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
gitlab_rails['registry_port'] = "5005"
gitlab_rails['registry_api_url'] = "http://localhost:5000"
gitlab_rails['registry_key_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/certificate.key"
gitlab_rails['registry_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/registry"
gitlab_rails['registry_issuer'] = "omnibus-gitlab-issuer"

# Settings used by Registry application
registry['enable'] = true
registry['username'] = "registry"
registry['group'] = "registry"
registry['uid'] = nil
registry['gid'] = nil
registry['dir'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/registry"
registry['log_directory'] = "/var/log/gitlab/registry"
registry['log_level'] = "info"
registry['rootcertbundle'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/registry/certificate.crt"
registry['storage_delete_enabled'] = true
```

---

Update

As per the logs below, I need **gitlab-registry.key** file in the correct location. What is this file and how do I generate one?

tail /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log

```
Started GET "/root/test/container_registry" for 125.99.49.46 at 2016-10-24 08:29:27 +0000
Processing by Projects::ContainerRegistryController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"namespace_id"=>"root", "project_id"=>"test"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)

Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab-registry.key):
  lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:20:in `read'
  lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:20:in `key_data'
  lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:24:in `key'
  lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:28:in `public_key'
  lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:33:in `kid'
  lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:12:in `encoded'
  app/services/auth/container_registry_authentication_service.rb:30:in `full_access_token'
  app/models/project.rb:421:in `container_registry_repository'
  app/controllers/projects/container_registry_controller.rb:28:in `container_registry_repository'
  app/controllers/projects/container_registry_controller.rb:8:in `index'
  lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:15:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:16:in `call'
```

---

Update 2

I guess I need to generate a certificate as explained here...

http://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Setup_HTTPS_for_Gitlab

Comment: Assuming the 500 error is an HTTP error, that is not "440 Page not found", it is "500 Internal server error". There *might* be an error log somewhere that expands on that generic error message.

Answer (score 1):

Check the GitLab server log (since it is an error 500. Example of such logs: [issue 23019](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23019))

There is an issue pending with GitLab 8.13: [23575: No way to enable container registry](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23575), with a merge request [7037: Fix typo in project settings that prevents users from enabling container registry](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/7037).
They *might* be related with your issue.

[Issue 23339](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23339) mentions also "sorting out self signed certs problem (my registry is under different domain than gitlab itself)": that should not be the case here.

[Issue 23181](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23181) (Pushing to Registry Still Frequently Encounters `unauthorized: authentication required`) suggests that the error is gone ofr docker 1.11+ (so it depends on which version of docker you are using on AWS)

---

Regarding `gitlab-registry.key` mentioned by the OP's edit, it should be created by a simple `reconfigure`, if declared properly.

So double-check:

- [`1316`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1316)

> It turns out it was a typo on my part.
>   The config key is `registry_nginx["ssl_certificate"]` not `registry_nginx[ssl_certificate]`.

- [1218](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1218) and [merge request 3787](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/3787) which show how this feature was added.

Comment: @shantanuo OK. I have added a couple of links to explore

Answer (score 1):

Try to set only few of the registry settings like :

```
registry_external_url 'http://ec2-54-167-34-63.compute1.amazonaws.com:4567'
```

Don't set the `gitlab_rail['registry']` and `registry['xxxxx']` if you want to keep the default values, and don't set values if you don't know what you are modifying.

About the certificates, check at the very bottom of the `gitlab.rb` file, and here you can set your certificates for the registry:

```
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/path/to/my/cert.crt"
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/path/to/my/key.key"
```

Also check the output of this commands to make a check of your GitLab instance:

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:check
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like [deporclick](http://www.deporclick.com) did, Set your certificates for the registry as:

```css
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/path/to/my/cert.crt"
registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/path/to/my/key.key"
```